# React - Child routes not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

So i'm trying to load some child routes using the new react-router. However, when i navigate to the address it shows just a blank screen. So far i only have two links, / and /about. What i want is a main page, that then loads components into that page. For example there is App.js. That is my main page with a dashboard that will link you to the other pages. Then there is two more pages home and about. I want home to load by default , and then when i click on the link i want the about page to be loaded into app instead of home. If i comment out the Link in Dashboard, the page loads, but if i leave Link in Dashboard, ill get errors. Can anyone see what is wrong or know how to achieve what i want?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';
ReactDOM.render(    
  <App/>
, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link, 
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import NotFound from './NotFound';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <Dashboard/>
        <Router>
          <div>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <h2>
            Home
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

about.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <h2>
            About
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

Errors

```
Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Link (at Dashboard.js:8)
    in li (at Dashboard.js:8)
    in ul (at Dashboard.js:7)
    in div (at Dashboard.js:6)
    in Dashboard (at App.js:25)
    in div (at App.js:20)
    in App (at index.js:7)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined
C:\Users\owner\MyWorkspace\Node\React-4\demo\node_modules\react-router-dom\es\Link.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$6sfrm3vc59' of null
    at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (C:\Users\owner\MyWorkspace\Node\React-4\demo\node_modules\react-dom\lib\ReactDOMComponentTree.js:113)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.js can you try replacing your  block with just App?

index.js:

`ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));`

It doesn't look like you need that block anyway.

Comment: I've seen exactly that error before actually - it's because ReactRouter has changed how its meant to be used in the latest version. Here's an example (based on some starter kit): https://github.com/dac09/cineme/blob/master/src/index.js with React router 3.x. For 4.x - I can't remember specifically, but you might have to install the history package and pass it in to Router as a prop